# Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 or Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3

I am new to java and maven. I want to build java project using java 11 and spring boot. When I build project from command line or from STS (IDE), it is successfully building, but when attempting to deploy my project from bitbucket to kubernetes pod using JAKS pipeline, I am getting below errors.

I am getting 'Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11' when I specify my configurations in my POM as

(a)

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

or
(b)

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>       
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

or
(c)

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>           
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

I am getting 'Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release' if I use any of below code

(a)

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>   
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>         
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

or

(b)

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>     
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Can some one help me understand why am I getting either of those errors, and what is the mistake am doing.  below is my pom.xml  to reference other dependencies and plugins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.staples</groupId>
<artifactId>plannerManger</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>plannerManger</name>
<description>planner manager</description>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>     
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>             
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using? After some [simple searching](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-release.html), I found that `--release` is available only after JDK 9.

Comment: This `Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11` means simply that you are not using a JDK 11 ...(or more accurate the option is available since JDK9+) as already commented.

Comment: Hi Geno Chen, I am using java 11

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons: the java binary specified at environment variable `JAVA_HOME` does not match the JDK version you are using in this project (JDK 11).

Run this in your command line:

> java -version

If it does not match your project version, you need to download JDK 11 and point the downloaded binary to your `JAVA_HOME`. You can download manually on websites, or use package managers to download and manage your java versioning.

I recommend package managers such as [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) [Java](https://scoop-docs.vercel.app/docs/guides/Java.html) for Windows and [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/install) for Unix-like platforms, as they offer downloads and management of java versions by automatically pointing `JAVA_HOME` to the latest JDK you installed using it. You can also change version at `JAVA_HOME` anytime you wish.

`scoop` instructions:

`scoop bucket add java`

`scoop search openjdk` to search list of available JDK/JREs in openjdk

`scoop install openjdk11` or whatever version listed.

Note that after you installed or changed your `JAVA_HOME`, please restart your IDE to take effect.

Comment: like I said, this is working fine in my local. I am getting error in jaks pipeline during building step.

Comment: Then I suppose your Jenkins build image should use a JDK 11 version to run your pipeline.

For example:
adoptopenjdk/openjdk11